# Type changes between two functions

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am working with the Next.js framework along with TypeScript. I have the following scenario during which a `string` type is being changed to `string[]` which subsequently throws a warning in typescript:

```
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from 'next';

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const { shortId } = context.params;
  const survey = await getSingleSurvey(shortId as string);

  return {
    props: { survey }
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const surveys = await getAllSurveys();

  const paths = surveys.map((survey) => {
    const shortId = shortenId(survey.id);
    const slug = titleToSlug(survey.title);

    return {
      params: {
        shortId,
        slug,
      },
    };
  });

  return {
    fallback: false,
    paths,
  };
};
```

In `getStaticPaths` you can see that I shorten the id (because cuid() is really long and I am using the id in my path). When hovering over the constant shortId, I am correctly seeing `const shortId: string`. Between returning this string from the map function and `getStaticProps` there seems to be a hiccup. When I hover over `const {shortId}...` in getStaticProps I am seeing the type `const shortId: string | string[]`. To resolve this I am casting shortId as a string right below, but if I didn't do so I'd get a warning that `Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

For these two questions, picture that I didn't cast shortId as string:

1. What's causing the discrepancy?
2. Is there an easier/better solution without type casting?

I'm still new to Typescript, go easy. Cheers

**EDIT**: getStaticProps' `context` is provided by the return of getStaticPaths. Hence I expect the values to be the same.
The type definitions are coming from next. Params has a type of `params?:  ParsedUrlQuery` which then goes on `interface ParsedUrlQuery extends NodeJS.Dict<string | string[]> { }`.

So I know why it's throwing the error, I just don't understand what is causing the warning when `string` is an accepted type. Do I always have to cast the type when facing the option `string | string[]` ?

**EDIT2**:

```
export const shortenId = (id: string): string => id.substr(2, 5);
```

Comment: Please show us the type definition of `GetStaticProps` and `GetStaticPaths`.

Comment: "*What's causing the discrepancy?*" - I see no indication why the types of the two `shortId` variables would be the same. One is created using `const { shortId } = context.params`, the other using `const shortId = shortenId(survey.id);`.

Comment: I'll add the clarification that the context params are provided to getStaticProps by getStaticPaths, so they should be the same.

Comment: you didn't show `shortenId` which is what determines the type of `shortId`...so, idk

Comment: My bad I thought that was all clear. I added the code

Comment: "*I just don't understand what is causing the warning when string is an accepted type*" - `string` is the *only* accepted type, but as the type definition says, the value you're passing in could also be an array of strings (in your case, apparently when the url looks like `?shortId=1&shortId=2`). So no, you shouldn't do any casting, rather you should add a typecheck.

Comment: Where would I add that? When I added it to {shortId} I’ve gotten the warning that string isn’t assignable to string | string[]